# What is a good way to recover from a fread() failure?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, recovery, fread

If a call to fread() returns 0 and ferror() indicates an error (vs. EOF), is it OK to retry the read or is it better to close and reopen the file?

I can't start over entirely -- the input file has been partially processed in a way that can't be undone (say I'm writing out a chunk at a time to a socket and, due to existing protocol, have no way of telling the remote end, "never mind, I need to start over").

I could fclose() and fopen() the file, fseek() past the data already processed, and continue the fread()-ing from there, but is all that necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no "one size fits all" solution, since different errors can require different handling. Errors from `fread()` are unusual; if you're calling it correctly, an error may indicate a situation that has left the `FILE*` in a weird error state. In that case you're best off calling `fclose()`, `fopen()`, `fseek()` to get things back in a good state.

If you're coding for something that's happening, please mention the actual errors you're getting from `ferror()`...

Comment: How can I tell what kind of error happened with fread()?  I don't think errno gets set (at least not according to the C standard).

fread() is being called correctly, the problem is with the underlying filesystem.

Comment: ferror() returns non-zero on error. Use that result to check for specific errors or hand off to perror()/strerror to see what you're getting.

Answer (score 6):

You can give the [`clearerr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/clearerr/) function a look.

Comment: Good point.  If I want to retry the fread() without closing/opening the file I'll need to clearerr() first.

Comment: FWIW, if you want to read a stream after an error you need to clear the error using clearerr. This behavior is defined by the standard as a portable thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the error to the user with `perror()` or `strerror()` and ask her is she wants to retry.

It's not mandatory for the implementation to provide such an error message, though. You should set `errno` to 0 before calling `fread()`; if it fails and `errno` is still 0 then no error information will be available.